# Guava event bus unregister all the event listeners

Tags: java, google-app-engine, guava, vaadin7

Are there any provision to unregister all the event bus listeners ? Like, when the application is about exit, and it has to do some clean up. I have some context where i'm unable to unregister with event bus.